# HttpResponse para retornar los datos de un modelo - DJango

Tags: django

Tengo definido el siguiente modelo:

```
class item (models.Model):
    DAYS_OF_WORKS = [
    ("LV", "LUNES A VIERNES"),
    ("LL", "LUNES A LUNES"),
    ]
    certificate=models.ImageField(default=None) 
    provider = models.ForeignKey(serviceProvider, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    radius = models.FloatField(default=None)
    description= models.TextField(blank = True)
    picture1=models.ImageField(default=None)    
    picture2=models.ImageField(default=None)    
    picture3=models.ImageField(default=None)    
    picture4=models.ImageField(default=None)    

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.radius)
```

En la siguiente lista tengo que retornar todos los modelos "items" que tiene cargado un "provider"

```
@csrf_exempt 
def completeInfoRubros (request,modo,tipo,user):
    if modo=="pedir":
        if tipo=="2":
            proveedores=serviceProvider.objects.filter(user=user)
            if not proveedores:
                return HttpResponse("No usuario registrado")
            else:
                rubros=item.objects.filter(provider=proveedores.first())
                if not rubros:
                    return ("No hay rubros cargados")
                else:
                    #aca tengo que devolver los tipos de items cargados
```

¿Necesariamente tengo que retornar esos datos con un template? o ¿puedo utilizar un return HttpResponse?

Answer (score 0):

como esperas recibir esos datos, ¿algún formato en especifico? ¿Estas usando ajax? ¿Cuál es tu objetivo? Si pudieras responder estas preguntas ayudaría a poder darte la mejor respuesta posible.

Si estas trabajando con ajax y esperas una respuesta en json te sugiero lo siguiente para regresar la información:

from django.http import JsonResponse

```
@csrf_exempt 
def completeInfoRubros (request,modo,tipo,user):
    data = dict()
    if modo=="pedir":
        if tipo=="2":
            proveedores=serviceProvider.objects.filter(user=user)
            if not proveedores:
                data['mensaje'] = "No usuario registrado"
            else:
                rubros=item.objects.filter(provider=proveedores.first())
                if not rubros:
                    data['mensaje'] = "No hay rubros cargados"
                else:
                    #aca tengo que devolver los tipos de items cargados
    
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

De esta manera recibiras el json:

```
{'mensaje': 'No usuario registrado'}
```

Ya solo en tu función success de tu ajax puedes manejar la información como mejor prefieras.

Si puedes detallar mas lo que pregunto arriba puedo actualizar mi respuesta.